# Django REST framework post array of objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, restangular

I am using [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for API and Angular SPA with Restangular to communicate with the API. Sometimes, I have to add more than one object using the API and I think I can send them together in an array and do this in one request.

I receive `wrong input` error when I'm trying to add more than one object from the REST framework web interface. I am passing objects or array of objects like below:

```
// this { "text": "gdhg", },{ "text": "gdhg", },{ "text": "gdhg", }
// or this [{ "text": "gdhg", },{ "text": "gdhg", },{ "text": "gdhg", }]
```

But I receive ParseError. Where I am wrong and what do I have to change to fix this?

Answer (score 24):

Another example that supports posting an array as well as posting a single object. Might be useful for anyone else looking for such an example.

```
class BookViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    ViewSet create and list books

    Usage single : POST
    {
        "name":"Killing Floor: A Jack Reacher Novel", 
        "author":"Lee Child"
    }

    Usage array : POST
    [{  
        "name":"Mr. Mercedes: A Novel (The Bill Hodges Trilogy)",
        "author":"Stephen King"
    },{
        "name":"Killing Floor: A Jack Reacher Novel", 
        "author":"Lee Child"
    }]
    """
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    search_fields = ('name','author')

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        #checks if post request data is an array initializes serializer with many=True
        else executes default CreateModelMixin.create function 
        """
        is_many = isinstance(request.data, list)
        if not is_many:
            return super(BookViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if the problem still exist. But the solution suggested by fiver did not work for me.
What works for me is overriding the `get_serializer` method ONLY.

> ```
> def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None,
>                     files=None, many=True, partial=False):
>     return super(ViewName, self).get_serializer(instance, data, files,
>                                                     many, partial)
> ```

If you will notice I am setting default `many=True` in arguments of `get_serializer`.
Apart from that nothing is required. Overridng of create method is also not required.

Also if you are defining the pre_save and post_save method in the views, expects the list(iterable) as the argument(as you are posting the list) of method not just a single object.

> ```
> def post_save(self, objects, *args, **kwargs):
>     """
>     In the post_save, list of obj has been created
>     """
>     for obj in objects:
>         do_something_with(obj)
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example for setting up bulk POSTing in a ListCreateAPIView using the Django REST Framework:

```
class SomethingList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Something
    serializer_class = SomethingSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                            headers=headers)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The important part here is the `many=True` argument to the `get_serializer()` method. Then, to make Angular play nice with this, you can define a service factory as:

```
.factory('Something', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        "url_to_something",
        {},
        {
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                isArray: true
            }
        }
    );
}])
```

Where the important part is the `isArray: true`. If you want to preserve posting single JSON objects, you could change `save` above to something like `saveBulk` or similar.

Comment: I did that with ModelViewSet and now receiving "'list' object has no attribute 'get'" because the request.DATA is list. How to fix this problem. I am testing it from the web interface of the api with sending json array of objects: [{ "text": "gdhg", },{ "text": "gdhg", },{ "text": "gdhg", }]

Answer (score 1):

Building on [vibhor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24280680/515537):

```
class ListableViewMixin(object):
    def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None, many=False, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ListableViewMixin, self).get_serializer(
            instance=instance, data=data, many=isinstance(instance, list) or isinstance(data, list),
            *args, **kwargs)
```

Make your view inherit from this mixin class to automatically determine if a `many=True` serializer should be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post a list you have to pass in `JSON` encoded data.

```
headers = {"Token": "35754sr7cvd7ryh454"}

recipients = [{'name': 'Ut est sed sed ipsa', 
               'email': 'dogoka@mailinator.com', 
               'group': 'signers'},
              {'name': 'Development Ltda.', 
               'email': 'test@test.com',
               'group': 'signers'}
             ]

requests.post(url, json=recipients, headers=headers)
```

requests.post(url, **json**=recipients, headers=headers)

Use `json` keyword argument (not `data`) so the data is encoded to `JSON` and the `Content-Type header` is set to `application/json`.

By default, Django Rest Framework assumes you are passing it a single object. To serialize a queryset or list of objects instead of a single object instance, you should pass the `many=True` flag when instantiating the serializer. You can then pass a queryset or list of objects to be serialized.

To do it, you'll have to override the `.create()` method of your view:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    many = True if isinstance(request.data, list) else False

    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=many)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects