# How to use transactions with Django REST framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I wish to use Django REST framework to create a number of model objects "together" -- i.e. in a single transaction.

The objective is that each of the objects will only be visible at the (successful) end of the transaction.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11):

Use `atomic` from `django.db.transaction` as a decorator around a function performing the database operations you are after:

If `obj_list` contains a list of populated (but not saved) model objects, this will execute all operations as part of one transaction.

`@atomic
def save_multiple_objects(obj_list):
   for o in obj_list:
     o.save()`

If you want to save multiple objects as part of the same API request, then (for example), if they are all of the same type, then you could POST a list of objects to an API endpoint - see [Django REST framework post array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881067/django-rest-framework-post-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by using `django db transactions`. Refer to the code below

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
    model_instance.creator = self.request.user
    model_instance.img_field.field.upload_to = 'directory/'+model_instance.name+'/logo'
    self.object = form.save()
```

This example is taken from my own answer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796383/django-set-the-upload-to-in-the-view/40018311#40018311). This way, `before calling save() you can save/edit other dependencies`